# MPI not running in parallel in a FORTRAN code

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I am trying to install an OpenMPI on my Ubuntu (14.04) machine, and I thought that I had succeeded, because I can run codes with **`mpirun`**, but recently I have noticed that it's not truly running in parallel.

I installed `openmpi` with the following options:

```
./configure CXX=g++ CC=gcc F77=gfortran \
                           F90=gfortran  \
                            FC=gfortran   \
         --enable-mpi-f77 \
         --enable-mpi-f90  \
         --prefix=/opt/openmpi-1.6.5
make all
sudo make install
```

As I said, I have run a code ( not written by myself ) and it seemed to work in parallel, because I checked with `top` and it was running in several nodes.

But now I have written a simple FORTRAN code:

```
PROGRAM hello_MPI
  INCLUDE "mpif.h"
  INTEGER :: err, size, rank
  CALL MPI_INIT(err)
  IF (err /= MPI_SUCCESS) STOP 'Init failed'
  CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, err)
  CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, err)
  PRINT*, "Hello world from process ", rank, " of ", size, " processes"
  CALL MPI_FINALIZE(err)
END PROGRAM
```

But when I run it with

```
mpirun -n 4 ./hello_MPI
```

I get the same output 4 times, showing that it is just running the same single process in 4 different processors

```
 Hello world from process            0  of            1  processes
 Hello world from process            0  of            1  processes
 Hello world from process            0  of            1  processes
 Hello world from process            0  of            1  processes
```

I have run this same code in a different machine and I get the expected output:

```
 Hello world from process            0  of            4  processes
 Hello world from process            1  of            4  processes
 Hello world from process            2  of            4  processes
 Hello world from process            3  of            4  processes
```

Comment: You might have already recognised, that the reported v 1.6.x is a way retired release. Check Open MPI for a bit more recent one ( v 3.0.0+ at the time of posting this ) and also use all the available diagnostic tools, as documented in `man mpirun` ( `--report-bindings` et al ) so as to better diagnose the problem -- so kindly review and update your actual code-execution environment details diagnosed down to the socket / core  maps and other in the original post here, to better document the context of use. Ok, Juan?

Comment: This typically happens when `mpirun` and `libmpi.so` do not match. For example if you use `mpirun` from Open MPI but your app was linked with MPICH or a different version of Open MPI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. It was quite silly, to be honest. For some reason I was not using the right OpenMPI installation (I have no idea which it was using). I recompiled using the right `mpif90` and run it using the right `mpirun` and now I get the expected result.
Sorry for the confusion, but I am quite new to this. And thank you for the help!