# Problems of mpirun for OpenMPI

Tags: fortran, openmpi, ubuntu-18.04

I installed openmpi-4.0.0 (https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v4.0/) as follow

```
./configure --prefix="/usr/local/openmpi"
make
sudo make install
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/openmpi/bin 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/openmpi/lib/
source ~/.bashrc  
sudo ldconfig
```

then enter the **examples** folder in the package, and use command:

```
make
mpirun -n 4 ./hello_usempi
```

it shows:

```
Hello, world, I am 0 of 1: Open MPI v2.1.1, package: Open MPI buildd@lcy01-amd64-009 Distribution, ident: 2.1.1, repo rev: v2.1.0-100-ga2fdb5b, May 10, 2017    
Hello, world, I am 0 of 1: Open MPI v2.1.1, package: Open MPI buildd@lcy01-amd64-009 Distribution, ident: 2.1.1, repo rev: v2.1.0-100-ga2fdb5b, May 10, 2017    
Hello, world, I am 0 of 1: Open MPI v2.1.1, package: Open MPI buildd@lcy01-amd64-009 Distribution, ident: 2.1.1, repo rev: v2.1.0-100-ga2fdb5b, May 10, 2017    
Hello, world, I am 0 of 1: Open MPI v2.1.1, package: Open MPI buildd@lcy01-amd64-009 Distribution, ident: 2.1.1, repo rev: v2.1.0-100-ga2fdb5b, May 10, 2017
```

The problem seems to be only one processor is activated. Note, both openmpi-4.0.0 and Ifort were installed on my computer. Could anyone please give me a hand, thanks very much.

I add the messages of the command `mpif90 -v` and `mpirun -v` here

`mpif90 -v`

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

`mpirun -v`

```
[mpiexec@tony-ThinkPad-P50] set_default_values (../../ui/mpich/utils.c:3178): no executable provided
[mpiexec@tony-ThinkPad-P50] HYD_uii_mpx_get_parameters (../../ui/mpich/utils.c:3620): setting default values failed
[mpiexec@tony-ThinkPad-P50] main (../../ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:438): error parsing parameters
```

The code is here (Copyright of Open MPI https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v4.0/)

```
! Copyright (c) 2004-2006 The Trustees of Indiana University and Indiana
!                         University Research and Technology
!                         Corporation.  All rights reserved.
! Copyright (c) 2004-2005 The Regents of the University of California.
!                         All rights reserved.
! Copyright (c) 2006-2015 Cisco Systems, Inc.  All rights reserved.
! $COPYRIGHT$
!
! Sample MPI "hello world" application using the Fortran mpi module
! bindings.

program main
    use mpi
    implicit none
    integer :: ierr, rank, size, len
    character(len=MPI_MAX_LIBRARY_VERSION_STRING) :: version

    call MPI_INIT(ierr)
    call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)
    call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierr)
    call MPI_GET_LIBRARY_VERSION(version, len, ierr)

    write(*, '("Hello, world, I am ", i2, " of ", i2, ": ", a)') &
          rank, size, version

    call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
end
```

The contents of the makefile are quite long, I think it is not convenient to post here, it is still in the install package of OpenMPI-4.0.0. Thank you once more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MPI not running in parallel in a FORTRAN code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417869/mpi-not-running-in-parallel-in-a-fortran-code)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet  Tony posted this there originally as an "answer" that got deleted. He/She should definitely explain why the answer there does not suffice and why does he have to ask a new question. We will need the output of `mpif90 -v` and `mpirun -v`. The `Makefile` for the code being run and **the code** itself. Tony, please see [mcve].

Comment: @Gilles Gouaillardet Thank you for your answer, I saw that question, but I can't deal with my problem following the answers there. For example, as you said that mpirun and libmpi.so do not match... and I don't know how to make them match.

Comment: @Vladimir F Thanks for your help. For your comments, as I mentioned above, it is still not solved for my case. Such as the post author said he/she use the right mpif90 and mpirun, I am not sure how to ensure the right selection. So I just want to ask the post author for help, and this is the first time to use stack overflow, I don't know how to leave him/her a message, hence I post my question to the answer box, sorry for that, maybe I should use a common.

Comment: @Vladimir F I have updated the question, thank you for your kind help.

Comment: Please add `which mpif90` and `which mpirun`.

Comment: `mpirun` is from MPICH. What does `ldd hello_use mpi` say ?

Comment: Never mind, simply add the path to Open MPI at the *beginning* of your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Rebuild and run again.

Comment: @Vladimir F Hi Vladimir, Merry Christmas! `which mpif90` gives /usr/bin/mpif90 and `which mpirun` gives /home/tony/ProgramFiles/IFort/composer_xe_2015.0.090/mpirt/bin/intel64/mpirun

Comment: @ Gilles Gouaillardet   Merry Christmas!  `ldd hello_use mpi`   says `linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd175cf000)
 libmpi_mpifh.so.20 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi_mpifh.so.20 (0x00007f75046d4000)
 libgfortran.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.4 (0x00007f75042f5000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7503f04000)
 libmpi.so.20 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.20 (0x00007f7503c12000)
 libopen-pal.so.20 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopen-pal.so.20 (0x00007f7503960000)`

Comment: `libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f7503741000)
 libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007f7503501000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7503163000)
 libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f7502f4b000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7504b2e000)
 libopen-rte.so.20 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopen-rte.so.20 (0x00007f7502cc3000)
 librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f7502abb000)`

Comment: `libhwloc.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhwloc.so.5 (0x00007f750287e000) 
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f750267a000)
 libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f7502477000)
 libnuma.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma.so.1 (0x00007f750226c000)
 libltdl.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007f7502062000)`

Comment: that is yet an other Open MPI (!). simply `export PATH=/usr/local/openmpi/bin:$PATH ; 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/openmpi/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, rebuild and re-run.

Comment: @Gilles Gouaillardet Ah yes, I make it following your suggestion. I am new to Linux, you help me a lot,  thank you very much. The suggestion of Vladimir F is also very helpful to me, thanks!

Comment: you likely have the MPICH runtime (only) in `/usr/bin`, so when you appended `/usr/local/openmpi/bin` to your `PATH`, you ended up using Open MPI `mpif90` but MPICH `mpirun`

Comment: @Gilles Gouaillardet I see, you gave a detailed answer.