# mpi4py not giving speed up on 2D block decomposition

Tags: mpi, mpi4py

I have been fiddling with distributed multiprocessing in python and have whipped up a 2D heat equation solver that uses a block-decomposition of the domain. This code performs identically (in terms of the right answer) to other MPI implementations in C and Fortran as well.

However, on my machine at 256x256 grid points and 4 processes, I do not see any speed up at all. In comparison, the C implementation (compiled with mpicc) gives me a nice speed up as expected. The curious thing is, when I deploy this code on a **different** machine (on the same number of processes) - I get the right speed up. The mpi4py and serial versions of this code may be found [here](https://github.com/Romit-Maulik/Tutorials-Demos-Practice/tree/master/mpi4py). I thought it may be due to cache size limitations but I get similar trends at lower numbers of grid points as well. Is there some sort of requirement for mpi4py that I'm missing that's causing the slowdown?

Comment: make sure you use the `mpirun` of the same MPI library that was used to build `mpi4py`, otherwise you will end up running 4 identical and serial tasks in parallel. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417869/mpi-not-running-in-parallel-in-a-fortran-code

Comment: Hi Gilles! Thank you for your comment. Both machines run openmpi 1.10.2 and have the same mpicc compiler wrapper. I double checked to ensure my mpi4py referred to the correct path when being built. My tasks do get executed in parallel (I have verified this) and the nodes do talk to each other correctly. However, individual cores take a longer time to finish their floating point operations.